# Resource not found error performing SSA create using dynamic client

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I was following @ymmt2005 excellent [dynamic client guide](https://ymmt2005.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/04/14/An_example_of_using_dynamic_client_of_k8s.io/client-go). All is good until the final step when I make the actual PATCH call, and I get a `the server could not find the requested resource` error. Just about everything seems right, except I'm unsure about the 'FieldManager' field in the PathOptions struct. I'm not sure what *"the actor or entity that is making these changes"* refers to. Does this need to match something in my code or system? Any other ideas?

```
package main

import (
...
)

const resourceYAML = `
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mike-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: 'nginx:latest'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
`

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Create dynamic discovery client from local kubeconfig file
    kubePath := filepath.Join(homedir.HomeDir(), ".kube", "config")
    cfg, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error building config, %v\n", err)
    }
    dynClient, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error creating client, %v\n", err)
    }
    disClient, err := discovery.NewDiscoveryClientForConfig(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error creating discovery client, %v\n", err)
    }

    // Decode YAML manifest & get GVK
    decodeUnstr := yaml.NewDecodingSerializer(unstructured.UnstructuredJSONScheme)
    obj := &unstructured.Unstructured{}
    _, gvk, err := decodeUnstr.Decode([]byte(resourceYAML), nil, obj)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error decoding manifest, %v\n", err)
    }
    jsonObj, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error marshaling object, %v\n", err)
    }

    // Find GVR using GVK
    mapper := restmapper.NewDeferredDiscoveryRESTMapper(memory.NewMemCacheClient(disClient))
    mapping, err := mapper.RESTMapping(gvk.GroupKind(), gvk.Version)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error finding GVR, %v\n", err)
    }

    // Get REST interface for the GVR, checking for namespace or cluster-wide
    var dr dynamic.ResourceInterface
    if mapping.Scope.Name() == meta.RESTScopeNameNamespace {
        // Namespaced resource
        dr = dynClient.Resource(mapping.Resource).Namespace(obj.GetNamespace())
    } else {
        // Cluster-wide resource
        dr = dynClient.Resource(mapping.Resource)
    }

    // Create or Update the object with SSA
    options := metav1.PatchOptions{FieldManager: "sample-controller"}
    _, err = dr.Patch(ctx, obj.GetName(), types.ApplyPatchType, jsonObj, options)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error patching, %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

[edit] I confirmed that I was only able to use 'Patch' on a resource that already existed. I tweaked the code to use 'Create' to create the resource, then I was able to successfully do a 'Patch' against it to change. To overcome the FieldManager inconsistencies I added Force=true to the PatchOptions which is recommended in the docs anyway. I'd still like to know how I can create if resource doesn't exist and update if it does--maybe just test for exist?

Comment: In looking a little closer at k8s REST apis, it seems like PATCH does not create a resource if it does not exist--which is consistent with the HTTP verb PATCH. Like 'kubectl apply -f', I would like a single command that creates a resource if it doesn't already exist. Is this possible?

Comment: ...or do I need to test if exists and then decide POST or PATCH? I'd like to keep the desired state (aka resource manifests), for a cluster, in Git and then have an agent update the resources for any new commits (aka changes to the resource manifests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is really trivial. The original code assumes that `namespace` is provided in the manifest. The deployment endpoint does not automatically set namespace to `default` if the provided namespace is "", and errors out because "" is not a valid namespace. Therefore, I added logic to set namespace to `default` if not provided and presto, the server side apply will create the resource if it doesn't exist and update if it does exist. Thanks again @ymmt2005 .

```
package main

import (
...
)

const resourceYAML = `
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mike-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: 'nginx:latest'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
`

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Create dynamic discovery client from local kubeconfig file
    kubePath := filepath.Join(homedir.HomeDir(), ".kube", "config")
    cfg, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error building config, %v\n", err)
    }
    dynClient, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error creating client, %v\n", err)
    }
    disClient, err := discovery.NewDiscoveryClientForConfig(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error creating discovery client, %v\n", err)
    }

    // Decode YAML manifest & get GVK
    decodeUnstr := yaml.NewDecodingSerializer(unstructured.UnstructuredJSONScheme)
    obj := &unstructured.Unstructured{}
    _, gvk, err := decodeUnstr.Decode([]byte(resourceYAML), nil, obj)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error decoding manifest, %v\n", err)
    }
    jsonObj, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error marshaling object, %v\n", err)
    }

    // Find GVR using GVK
    mapper := restmapper.NewDeferredDiscoveryRESTMapper(memory.NewMemCacheClient(disClient))
    mapping, err := mapper.RESTMapping(gvk.GroupKind(), gvk.Version)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error finding GVR, %v\n", err)
    }

    // Set Namespace to default if not provided in manifest
    var ns string
    if ns = obj.GetNamespace(); ns == "" {
        ns = "default"
    }

    // Get REST interface for the GVR, checking for namespace or cluster-wide
    var dr dynamic.ResourceInterface
    if mapping.Scope.Name() == meta.RESTScopeNameNamespace {
        // Namespaced resource
        dr = dynClient.Resource(mapping.Resource).Namespace(ns)
    } else {
        // Cluster-wide resource
        dr = dynClient.Resource(mapping.Resource)
    }

    // Create or Update the object with SSA
    options := metav1.PatchOptions{FieldManager: "sample-controller"}
    _, err = dr.Patch(ctx, obj.GetName(), types.ApplyPatchType, jsonObj, options)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error patching, %v\n", err)
    }
}
```